# Deleting a folder and all of its contents if the folder has more than 1 million files

Tags: linux, centos, delete-file, directory

I am trying to delete a folder that is used in my cdn and it creates new folders for each file viewed. This means that for every file requested their is a folder. This has stacked up to about a 100 million folders inside my main folder.

How would I go about deleting all of the contents inside? Because when I try rm -rf it gives me the error of Argument List too Long.

Comment: What is your exact command line? Because `rm -rf` by itself doesn't do anything. What arguments are you providing?

Comment: Exactly what you're trying to delete is a little unclear. You're saying "go about deleting all the contents inside" but your title says, "deleting a folder and all its contents". If it's the folder and it's contents, just use `rm -rf folder_name`. That deletes `folder_name` and everything inside of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete file in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952355/delete-file-in-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is bit confusing and certainly belong to serverfault but..

Probably, what you are trying to do is something like:

```
rm -rf *
```

The error message "Argument List too Long" is from bash that have a fixed memory size for argument list. So when you run `rm -rf *`, bash first create a list of every file/folder before deleting them. To see the size:

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

If you want to delete the entire folder, just `rm -rf folder/*` should work.

But if you want delete files inside folder.

```
find /folder/ -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This every directory found (-type d) with find you be removed one by one.